# Get Orders from Specific Date Range in Shopify

Tags: python, shopify

I'm trying to get all orders processed in one day (previous day) shown in the code below.

```
date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%Y-%m-%d')

response = requests.get(url="https://shopname.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?processed_at_min=" + date + "&processed_at_max=" + date + "&fulfillment_status=shipped")

print(response.text)
```

The output gives me the following

```
{"orders":[]}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have no idea if any of those orders are actually fulfilled and marked as shipped, so that empty set could be perfectly correct.

Second, check for the filter as created_at and not processed_at. I believe from my years of use that it has always been created_at and never processed_at, but of course, Shopify changes all the time, so that could work too.

Alos be aware that if there were > 50 orders that did fit the filter, you would not see them with this code, as it has no paging capability built in.